# Async map function call to API returning an Array of undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm quite new to Promises in JavaScript. I'm attempting to call an API to get calendar events using calendar IDs in an array. I do this by calling the API in a map function and attempt to put the resulting object as an array. However the result is simply an array of undefined objects.

From my Googling, `Promises.all()` should run when an async method completes. Why then are the `results` undefined?

PS: I debugged and can see the `calendarObj` is getting loaded from the API call correctly, however `results` is still undefined.

```
async function getCalendarEvents(calendarList) {
    if (debug) {
        console.log("searching between " + this.query.timeMin + " and " + this.query.timeMax);
    }
    var calendars = [];
    // Loop through all calendars and extract events
    const results = calendarList.map(async (calendar, i) => {
        if (calendar.summary != "Holidays in United Kingdom") {
            this.client.events.list({
                calendarId: calendar.id,
                timeMin: this.query.timeMin,
                timeMax: this.query.timeMax,
                maxResults: this.query.maxResults,
                singleEvents: true,
                orderBy: 'startTime',
            }, (err, res) => {
                if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);

                const events = res.data.items;

                if (events.length) {
                    if (debug) // true
                        console.log("Loading " + events.length + " events for " + calendar.summary);

                    var calendarObj = {
                        name: calendar.summary,
                        id: calendar.id,
                        events: events
                    };
                    // calendars.push(calendarObj);
                    return calendarObj;
                } else {
                    if (debug)
                        console.log('No upcoming events found for ' + calendar.summary);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    Promise.all(results).then((completed) => console.log(completed)); // returns an array of undefined
}
```

Console Output: [image]

Comment: call me crazy, but I don't see an API call anywhere

Comment: Your `async` function neither returns a Promise nor does it use `await`

Comment: Your `async (calendar, i) => { … }` does not `return` anything, that's why you're getting `undefined`. And it doesn't `await` anything either. You need to promisify your `this.client.events.list(…)` function - don't use a callback!

Comment: @markb - this.client.events.list ?

Comment: `Promises.all() should run when an async method completes` - correction, `Promise.all` (not Promises.all) resolves when all the Promises passed in the argument resolve (note, they don't even have to be all or any promises)